# Android RecyclerView SelectionTracker clears selection on touch outside

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement the android library [SelectionTracker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker) which allows to select items in a recyclerView.

Everything works fine except that when I click outside of an 
[item (which is in a grid layout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iQVZ.png), the all selection is cleared.

I actually have found the code which calls the `clearSelection()`. It's on the line 78 of the class [TouchInputHandler](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/support-library-27.1.1/recyclerview-selection/src/main/java/androidx/widget/recyclerview/selection/TouchInputHandler.java).
It then calls the line 64 of [ItemDetailsLookup](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/support-library-27.1.1/recyclerview-selection/src/main/java/androidx/widget/recyclerview/selection/ItemDetailsLookup.java) which returns `false` because the touch event didn't occurred on an item.

I was wondering if anyone have found a workaround to prevent this behavior, because I didn't found any option in the documentation.

It's a gridLayout so it is quite "normal" to have space between items and I don't want my users to clear the selection because they have touch the side of an item.

Comment: hey, was wondering if you found a solution to this?

Comment: nope sorry! I drop this for the meanwhile and still hoping of getting an answer...

Comment: You can now check V-master' solution.

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution, based on that if we have predefined ItemDetail that will be used as "this is not the view you can select".

First, inside your ItemDetailsLookup instead of returning `null` you can pass single item with distinguish data that will make sure there is no name/position collision with any other data you can have

```
class AppItemDetailsLookup(private val rv: RecyclerView) : ItemDetailsLookup<String>() {

    override fun getItemDetails(e: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<String>? {
        val view = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y) ?: return EMPTY_ITEM

        return (rv.getChildViewHolder(view) as AppItemViewHolder).getItemDetails()
    }

    object EMPTY_ITEM : ItemDetails<String>() {
        override fun getSelectionKey(): String? = "empty_item_selection_key_that_should_be_unique_somehow_that_is_why_i_made_it_so_long"
        override fun getPosition(): Int = Integer.MAX_VALUE
    }

}
```

And then when you are creating SelectionTracker with builder, instead of using standard predicate (default is `SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()`) you make your own that will notify that this `EMPTY_ITEM` cannot be selected

```
.withSelectionPredicate(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate<String>() {
    override fun canSelectMultiple(): Boolean = true
    override fun canSetStateForKey(key: String, nextState: Boolean): Boolean =
        key != AppItemDetailsLookup.EMPTY_ITEM.selectionKey

    override fun canSetStateAtPosition(position: Int, nextState: Boolean): Boolean =
        position != AppItemDetailsLookup.EMPTY_ITEM.position
})
```

I tested it with LinearLayoutManger, the selection was deselecting all items once i clicked outside any of them (my items did not had spacing decoration, but there were so few of them that i was seeing empty under last item)

Answer (score 0):

This is an official workaround from this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177046288. It's nice, because it's short and also fixes clearing selection when clicking on an `ItemDivider`. Just make sure to call this *before* creating the `SelectionTracker`.

```kotlin
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val down = event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
        if(!down || !selectionTracker!!.hasSelection()) {
            return false //Don't intercept, otherwise you break scrolling
        }

        val view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(event.x, event.y)
        return view == null
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) { }
    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) { }
})
```